# WebDAV folder quota using Apache server

Tags: apache, limit, webdav, quota

I am trying to set up a WebDAV folder on my CentOS server.  I have for the most part succeeded.  My problem is that I am trying to set up a size limit (quota) on the folder.  I found a blog that spelled out how to do that using the "DAVSATMaxAreaSize" command.  However, when I restart Apache, I get the error: "Invalid command 'DAVSATMaxAreaSize', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration".  Does this mean the module that supports this command is not installed?  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to recompile your apache.

1. Download patch from http://www.geocities.jp/t_sat7/webdav/webdav.html
2. Download rpm source for apache from centos repos. Patch it with patch u downloaded and recompile apache.

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem on my `Ubuntu 12.04` server but I didn't want to recompile my `apache`. I "solved" it as follows:

1. I created a file container using dd (for 100MB):

   `dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/webdav-file-container bs=1048576 count=100`
2. And created a filesystem in that container:

   `mkfs.ext4 /var/webdav-file-container`
3. Then I mounted this container as folder for my share:

   `mount /var/webdav-file-container /var/webdav-share`

So, now the filesystem in the container has a fixed size and apache cannot write more than the 100MB.
The only thing is that the user does not know how much space is left on that share. The Windows client report the size of it's own system drive ...